# Not receiving notifications

Tags: support, notifications

I am not receiving notifications for people commenting or responding to my questions. Under **Edit Profile and Settings > Preferences > Q&A Emails** I have checked the box "Email me my unread inbox messages" and of course the email address is correct...

I have seen similar questions but either they were not answered or the answers show a different interface than I see in my profile (or I simply failed to find the right answer).

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How long are you waiting for notifications?

Comment: @KazWolfe, I haven't yet received the notification for a comment from May 27th.

Comment: have you read the comment?

Comment: @Zanna: which comment?

Comment: The one you were expecting a notification about. If you read the comment, you don't get notified about it...

Comment: Gotcha. Nope... In fact I saw yours yesterday (or your new one today) just because I randomly opened the page.

Comment: In that case, +1 to your question... did you set the time? 3 hours, daily or weekly are the options

Comment: @Zanna the notification frequency was set correctly. But I found that after creating a Stack Overflow account, things started working, as I describe in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I am now receiving notifications. I realized that I had created an account on Ask Ubuntu without creating one for Stack Exchange itself. It seems that, after creating a Stack Exchange account, I was able to get notifications. As dumb as it is that I didn't do it before, I hope this helps others.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. Do you mean you hadn't added an account for Stack *Exchange*? That also shouldn't be necessary. You need to add your email address of course... is that what was missing?

Comment: Yes, @Zanna, that was a Freudian slip. I edited my answer. If that's not the reason, I don't know why it wasn't working before, my email was already in the system, and I had double-checked that it was correct.

Comment: I made a Stack Exchange account last week - been signing in with my Launchpad OpenID all this time and getting notifications perfectly fine! So still baffled. But glad you fixed it...